How to pass data between composable screens in android compose app?
I want to pass data between 1st composable screen to 4th composable screen. How we can pass data from 1st screen to 4th screen without passing to 2nd and 3rd through navgraph?

Please show us the code you have so far and provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

I think you are navigating like from 1st -> 2nd -> 3rd -> 4th if yes then Method 1 will just work fine for you but still I mention some more ways.
Method 1: You can declare a variable in the MainActivity to store the data and while navigation to the 1st composable you can initialize it and then use that variable in your 4th composable this is how the data is saved depends on the lifecycle of that Activity.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    // declare the variable here
    lateinit var myData: Data

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            NavHost(
                // ... mandatory parameters
            ) {
                // 1st composable
                composable(route = "first_screen") {
                    mydata = // initialize variable here
                }
                // ... here comes other composables
                // 4th composable
                composable("fourth_screen") {
                    // Use myData here according to your needs
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Method 2: If you navigate directly from 1st composable to the 4th composable you can just pass the data in the route. To know how to do that you can check the Offical documentation for Navigation with Compose.
Method 3: I know this is not your need but still In my opinion this can be the best way to make proper parameter flow so you can just pass the data from 1st -> 2nd -> 3rd -> 4th.

I think it is not a good practice to use variables on the Activity level in a Jetpack Compose app.

You should use a ViewModel to store your data. Then you can scope a ViewModel to either

the whole App
a NavGraph
one destination in a NavGraph (a NavBackStackEntry). This however is not what you want in your current case.

Please have a look at this stackoverflow question for detailed solutions and explanations. I will give a short summary here.
One simple way to create a global app-wide ViewModel is like this:
val appStateViewModel = viewModel()
NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
    //...
    ScreenA(appStateViewModel.myData)
    //...
    ScreenB(appStateViewModel.myData)
    //...
    ScreenC(appStateViewModel.myData)
}

If you need one data element to be available in three different screens, you can consider to add these three routes to a nested NavGraph. Then do something like this:
NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {

    // a nested NavGraph
    navigation(startDestination = nestedStartRoute, route = nestedRoute) {
        composable(route) {
            // This instance will be the same
            val navigationGraphEntry = remember { navController.getBackStackEntry(nestedRoute) }
            val graphScopedViewModel = viewModel(navigationGraphEntry)
            ScreenA(graphScopedViewModel.myData) // pass ViewModel data to Composable
        }
        composable(route) {
            // as this instance
            val navigationGraphEntry = remember { navController.getBackStackEntry(nestedRoute) }
            val graphScopedViewModel = viewModel(navigationGraphEntry)
            ScreenB(graphScopedViewModel.myData) // pass ViewModel data to Composable
        }
    }
    navigation(startDestination = nestedStartRoute, route = secondNestedRoute) {
        composable(route) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

Note that I could not test the code right now, but this should be enough to get you started.
